# GREP numeric range

Tags: unix, grep

I have log file in following format

```
14:15
14:16
14:17
14:30
14:31
14:41
```

I want to grep based on 15 minute time interval. 
So in one case I want to grep time b/w 14:0-14:15
in another case I want to grep time b/w 14:15 14:30

Is there a way to do that in grep ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -v start=14:15 -v end=14:30 'start<=$1 && $1<=end' log.txt
14:15
14:16
14:17
14:30
```